# Script to join WPA2 Enterprise wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, command-line, applescript, ifconfig

When I head to work with my MBP running OSX 10.7, I have to go through this series:

- Join Other Network
- Enter SSID
- select Security = WPA2 Enterprise
- generate a pw via my RSA soft token
- Join

Two interesting limitations here: the SSID is hidden until I enter it in manually, and I *don't* want to save the password since I generate a new one every time.

Q: What `ifconfig` syntax is needed to script this out?

I'd like to make a script that prompts me for the current token... I'll then convert it to an apple script so it's stupid simple.

Thanks for your input! Please feel free to ignore the AppleScript part as we're in SuperUser.. I'll reach out for that part on the apple net.